# Emberjs: UPDATED The response from a findQuery must be an Array, not undefined

Tags: ember.js

I haved a google auto complete search box that keeps updating search.
the below code works for two searched and then I get The response from a findQuery must be an Array, not undefined.

unloading the store address and hotel data for every new search may not be a good thing. but i cannot think of any other solution for now.

```
Lost.HotelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
queryParams: {
    currentPlace: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
},
model: function (params) {
    var self = this;
    var hotelController = this.controllerFor('hotel');
    var currentPlace = hotelController.get('currentPlace');
    self.store.unloadAll('address');
    self.store.unloadAll('hotel');
    return this.store.find('address', {
        locality: currentPlace
    }).then(function (response) {
        return self.store.all('hotel');
    });
},
deactivate: function () {
    this.controllerFor('city').set('routeNeedsAutoSearch', false);
}
```

});

Comment: Is `find('address',{currentPlace})` a typo? Should it be `find('address',{locality: currentPlace})` as above?

Comment: thanks it is ('address',currentPlace) as my component passes proper object for it. still the same error exists

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach.
I guess this is the a good way to do it unloading data for each search. 
A better way is to user this.store.filter
so I am doing something like this now.

**I may not be right I am learning so if some one suggest a better any I will select that as appropriate answer**

```
return this.store.find('address', {
    locality: currentPlace
}).then(function (response) {
        response.forEach(function (item) {
           addressId = item.get('id');
           arr = self.store.filter('hotel', function (hotel) {
           return hotel.get('address.id') == addressId;
        });
    });
});
```